# Solve the equation $4^{7 x - 10} = 10^{7 x - 6}$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $x$ of the following equation.

$$4^{7 x - 10} = 10^{7 x - 6}$$

I tried to make $4$ and $10$ have a common base but I could not find one so I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
& 4^{7 x - 10} = 10^{7 x - 6} \\[6pt]
\implies & \log_4(4^{7 x - 10}) = \log_4(10^{7 x - 6}) \\[6pt]
\implies & 7x-10 = (7x-6)\log_4(10) \\[6pt]
\implies & 7x-7x\log_4(10) = 10-6\log_4(10) \\[6pt]
\implies & 7x[1-\log_4(10)] = 10-6\log_4(10) \\[6pt]
\implies & 7x = \frac{10-6\log_4(10)}{1-\log_4(10)} \\[6pt]
\implies & x = \frac{10-6\log_4(10)}{7-7\log_4(10)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$4^{7x-10}=10^{7x-6}=10^4 10^{7x-10}\implies\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{7x-10} =\left(\frac{4}{10}\right)^{7x-10}=10^4.$$

Now take logarithms and you will get an equation in $x.$

Comment: how is 4^7x-10 equivalent to (2/5)^(7x-10)?

Comment: I have divided both terms of the equality by $10^{7x-6}.$ Then I have simplified $4/10=2/5.$

Comment: what happens to the 7x-6 that is the exponent of the 10

Comment: I have used the property $a^ma^n=a^{m+n}.$ That is, $10^410^{7x-10}=10^{7x-10+4}=10^{7x-6}.$

Comment: If you divide both terms of the equality by 10^7x-6, how can you use that property? Wouldnt you be diving a^m by a^n not multiplying?

Comment: $\dfrac{4^{7x-10}}{10^{7x-10}}=\left(\dfrac 2 5\right)^{7x-10}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Its 10^7x-6 not 10 though. What am I missing

Comment: We multiply and divide $10^{7x-6}$ by $10^4$ just to have the same exponent in both sides of the equality.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need both sides to have the same base.  You can take $\ln$ of both sides.  This allows you to bring the exponents down.

If you do want both sides to have the same base then convert each side to base $e$, note that for any number $a > 0$ and $a \neq 1$ we have that

$a^b = e^{b \ln(a)}$

Rewriting both sides to have base $e$ and then equating exponents is the same thing as taking $\ln$ of both sides.

Comment: If I take ln of both sides, and then move the exponent in front of the natural log where do I go from there without canceling out the 7x's with each other by trying to get them all on one side?

Answer (score 0):

$$4^{7x - 10} = 10^{7x - 6}$$
$$(7x - 10)\log4 = (7x - 6)\log10$$
$$7x = \frac{6\log10 - 10\log4}{\log10 - \log4}$$
$$ = \frac{6\log5 + 6\log2 - 20\log2}{\log5 + \log2 - 2\log2}$$
$$ = \frac{6\log5 - 14\log2}{\log5 - \log2}$$
$$ x = \frac{2(3\log5 - 7\log2)}{7(\log5 - \log2)}$$